# Does Google Analytics tracks referrals when site is down

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I am using Google Analytics to track visitors to the site. Now I have started a PPC campaign and I had a problem with the site which was down for a few hours, from 9am to 12am. So I wonder if Google Analytics can count the clicks from the PPC campaign even the application on the site is down.

There are two opinions on it, so I am a bit confused. One says GA track the visit but cannot track deeper than the visit, also Google Web Master Tools can say this information. The opposite idea says if application is down, so does the ga.js therefore GA cannot count any data.

Also, can Google Web Master tools tell me if the application is down or not. I found some services to let me know if the server is down but in this case I need to track if the app is down.

I would love to hear any comments on this question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

User's browser can only send data to Google Analytics if the page is loaded, so if the site is down, nothing can be sent.

As for a uptime monitoring service, quick googling gives http://mashable.com/2010/04/09/free-uptime-monitoring/. I believe that Google Web Master tools provide website alerts but they don't have an option to send notifications.

Comment: Thank you @maxivanov. So I will need to figure out another way :)

Comment: if I add a index.html and add the gs.js and redirect to the application does it double count the visitors? or is there any risk on it?

Comment: Well it depends on what you mean under "the website is down". If there is some hardware/network issue, you won't be able to serve index.html page as well. And if the problem is within an app (i.e. webserver can answer browser's requests), the app itself must serve an error page, which would have GA code embedded.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research on the topic I have found and tried what Google said in this [link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009614?hl=en)
Now I can place a cookie to visitor and can match PPC cound with visitor count.